Adventure (probably) movie, where an emperor queen force chained slaves to jump into a hole with lava pool
I'm looking for a movie in which an emperor queen has a group of chained slaves thrown into a hole with a lava pool.
This may sound weird, but that’s all I remember about the movie - a single scene, but it was quite drastic:

So, basically, the queen sits on a throne.
Chained slaves/prisoners beg her about something, but suddenly she just points her finger into a hole. The hole is between her throne and the chained group.
They know it’s a death sentence and start screaming, or something. Soldiers or guards throw them into the hole and, because of the chain, those who already jumped trigger the rest of slaves to be sucked into the hole.
Before they jump, there’s a camera shot that clearly shows that, inside the hole, or beneath the surface, there’s a huge lava pool. So basically, the group jumps into a volcano that’s on the lower level of the room where they are now.

The last scene before they all disappear (in the lava, obviously) is where the part of the chained slaves is still in the hole but hasn't touched the lava (yet). There’s obviously no chance of them surviving.
Can you help me identify this movie, or point me to this scene on Youtube or somewhere?
Sorry if there's too much of a lack of information, but that’s all I know.

As for the release year of the movie? No idea. I watched it in the mid-90s, but I assume the movie was from 80s - or maybe 70s? Definitely not earlier, due to the movie effects.
The movie was definitely in colour, not black and white.
And, with a probability of 80%, English was the language the actors were speaking.
The setting of the movie was something like a medieval fantasy - no cars or guns etc. 

One answer was already provided (and deleted after I said it's not the movie I'm looking for):

Red Sonja - is a wrong guess.


The Dark Secret sound like something and it could be that?

This movie is too old (so maybe just to exclude it), but it contains a fitting scene: She from 1965 featuring Ursula Andress as queen Ayesha. In 1918, a British expedition finds the city of Kuma in Africa. Ayesha is immortal and rules over that realm.
Here is the scene, in which slaves a thrown into a lava pit:




Yes! That's the movie I was looking for! I remember only this scene. Thanks a lot! :)
